# Filter an Array of mixed elements

Tags: typescript

Given JSON of:

```
 {
    "animals": [
        {
            "dog": {
                "name": "Buster",
                "breed": "Poodle",
                "collarTag": "ABCDEF9999"
            }
        },
        {
            "snake": {
                "name": "Sammy",
                "species": "Copperhead"
            }
        },
        {
            "dog": {
                "name": "Rex",
                "breed": "Mixed",
                "collarTag": "ABCDEF1234"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to transform the array of mixed elements to an array that only includes dogs and the last 4 digits of the "collarTag". What is the best way to do this, filter, reduce, something else? and how would it be done. I am not the strongest at TypeScript and get hung up on some of the simple things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nikolai has a good answer, and if you wanted to use reduce instead of filter & map..

```
const dogs = Object.values(json.animals).reduce((acc, el) => {
  if (!el.dog) return acc;
  acc.push( {
    name: el.dog.name,
    collarTag: el.dog.collarTag.slice(-4),
  })
  return acc
}, []);
```

Comment: thank you for the help, I am not sure if I can mark 2 as the answer but I will try

Answer (score 2):

```js
const dogs = (Object.values(json.animals).filter(el => {
    return !!el.dog
}).map(el => {
    return {
        name: el.dog?.name,
        collarTag: el.dog?.collarTag.slice(-4)
    }
}))

console.log(dogs)
```